# SQL Server get Identity Number and assign to another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, varchar

I am a beginner SQL Server student and need to fulfill a requirement and don't know how

For table `Products` I have columns `ProductID`, `ProductName`, `SerialNo`.

The `SerialNo` should start from 1001 and increment by 1 and at the same time `ProductId` should start as `P1001`, `P1002` and so...

I defined

```
SerialNo INT Identity(1001, 1)
```

and don't know how to take the identity value and append it to 'P' and tried using variables and can't figure it out

```
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ProductID VARCHAR(5)
    SET @ProductID = 'P' + CAST(@@IDENTITY AS VARCHAR)
    INSERT INTO Product VALUES(@ProductID,'Nokia')
    SELECT * FROM Product
END
```

I got

```
ProductID       Name        SerialNo
--------------------------------------
NULL            NOKIA       1001
```

Expected output is

```
ProductID       Name        SerialNo
-------------------------------------
P1001            NOKIA       1001
```

Comment: You can insert by empty productId and then update it

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` returns the value of the `IDENTITY` for a prior `INSERT`, not one that hasn't happened yet. Use a coln defined with an `IDENTITY` property and then a computed column for your value with the prefix.

Comment: Otherwise, if you must define the value prior to inserting, look into `SEQUENCE` objects.

Comment: Have a computed column, or create a view. Why store derived data in the table?

Comment: I didn't say it was here, @Charlieface ? I stated why `@@IDENTITY` isn't working and to use a computed column... Like Gordon demonstrate's in  their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66627343/2029983). That doesn't require `@@IDENTITY`, *or* `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@@IDENTITY keeps the last insert identity in the session, so its not useful for you , you have several option:

- add a computed column :

  ```
  alter table product add ProductId as concat('P',SerialNo)
  ```
- use IDENT_CURRENT :
  IDENT_CURRENT give you the last identity values in the table

  ```
  INSERT INTO Product VALUES(concat('P',IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.product')+1) ,'Nokia')
  SELECT * FROM Product
  ```

I recommend you go with computed column , however you always can reproduce the productId , not sure why you need to save it , its redundunt

Comment: The saving part is for concept learning..Thank you for the answer. Much appreciated

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Scope identity doesn’t work as we don’t have anything inserted yet in this scenario but yes preferred over @@identity

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest created a generated column:

```
alter table product add column ProductId as concat('P', SerialNo);
```

This is calculated when the column is referenced (unless the value is persisted).

To be honest, I'm not sure if you really need such a column.  The identity column should be sufficient.

Comment: How would the INSERT Statement look like ? Thank You for the Answer

Comment: @ThomasAMathew . . . You simply don't insert the `ProductId`.  It is calculated when referenced (or automatically if the column is persisted).