# How to create value to be inserted based on identity in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is how I do it on my stored procedure:

```
SET @ProductCode = CONCAT('P',RIGHT ('0000'+ CAST (IDENT_CURRENT('[dbo].[Products]') + 1 AS varchar), 5))
```

This problem with this is when inserting the first record.

It starts with 2

Actual result:

| ProductId | ProductCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P00002 |
| 2 | P00003 |
| 3 | P00004 |
| 4 | P00005 |

Expected result:

| ProductId | ProductCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P00001 |
| 2 | P00002 |
| 3 | P00003 |
| 4 | P00004 |

Comment: Remove the `+ 1`.

Comment: This looks [familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66627384/2029983). I, personally suggest doing what all the comments, and [@GordonLinoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66627343/2029983) on the other question suggest; use a computed column.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql), `IDENT_CURRENT` returns *"the last identity value generated for a specific table or view"*. Thus, in the case of an INSERT, it would return the identity value  generated for the row currently to be inserted. So you can just use `IDENT_CURRENT` and don't need to increment it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff omg ur right

Comment: My guess, @derpirscher , as the OP has omitted much of their code, is that their are assigning the value after their `INSERT`, and then adding `1`; thus the incorrect value. If that *is* the case, they should be using `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, not `IDENT_CURRENT`, as they'll have problems when multiple inserts occur at once. In truth, the design is likely flawed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I take it back. it didnt

Comment: Either use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for a single insert, or `OUTPUT` into a table variable for multiple rows. If you want to have it in the table at the same time as the insert, use a computed column

Comment: Again, @ByronScott, use a Computed Column, like your fellow student was shown in the answer I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

With your current table structure, you should declare a table variable. Then use the `OUTPUT INTO` clause to get the newly inserted values. This will work irrespective whether your ProductId column is identity or not.

```
declare @Output table (ProductId bigint, ProductCode varchar(255))

insert into Products (FieldA, FieldB)
output inserted.ProductId, 'P' + Format(inserted.ProductId, '0000') into @Output
values ('Test A1', 'Test B1')
      ,('Test A2', 'Test B2')
      ,('Test A3', 'Test B3')

select * from @Output
```

[image: result]

If it is possible to modify your table structure, I would suggest adding a computed column to avoid all these hassles.

```
alter table Products
add ProductCode as 'P' + Format(ProductId, '0000')
```

This would create a computed column which you can query as any other regular column.

[image: computed column]

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query (I have removed (+1) )

```sql
    SET @ProductCode = CONCAT('P',RIGHT ('0000'+ CAST (IDENT_CURRENT('[dbo].[Products]')  AS varchar), 5))
```

But I would recommend to add Product_Code as computed column;

> ```
> create table products (ProductId int,ProductCode as CONCAT('P',RIGHT ('0000'+ cast( productid  as varchar(4)), 5))  )
> ```

> ```
> insert into products values(1);
> insert into products values(2);
> insert into products values(3);
> ```

> ```
> select * from products
> ```

**Output:**

> | ProductId | ProductCode |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | P00001 |
> | 2 | P00002 |
> | 3 | P00003 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90df4be802a2ded92773af2493f01e9d)*

Comment: `IDENT_CURRENT` is almost never the right answer to anything

Comment: Actually I just tried to answer why product_code is starting from P00002 instead of P00001.

Comment: That's fair enough, but you should also correct other obvious mistakes at the same time. We shouldn't perpetuate bad code on [so]

Comment: That's true. Thanks. I always appreciate your ethical concern. Will try to suggest a better option. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Charlieface You just spoke my mind. I have also suggested a computed column.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `ProductId` that you already have??

```
SET @ProductCode = CONCAT('P', RIGHT('0000'+ CAST(ProductId AS VARCHAR(5)), 5))
```

Or as @Larnu suggested in a comment - use a **computed column** in your table with this logic:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD ProductCode AS CONCAT('P', RIGHT('0000'+ CAST(ProductId AS VARCHAR(5)), 5)) PERSISTED;
```

and be done with it. Every time a row is inserted, your column `ProductCode` is computed and shows the expected values.

Comment: One problem with padding 0's using `RIGHT('0000'...` approach is estimating the number of 0's to pad. This gets solved by using `FORMAT` function. e.g. The above code will work upto ProductId=9999 but will fail beyond that.